# How to show the error messages in danger in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Have created form as First_Name and Last_Name..
Is there any generic forms validator in Angular 2 and also I have shown the error message in client-side. How to display the in danger!!

Bellow is my code

html file

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"  (ngSubmit)="submit()" >

<ion-item>
  <ion-label primary floating>FIRST NAME</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname" minlength="4" maxlength="12" required ></ion-input>
</ion-item>  
  <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.firstname.errors && myForm.controls.firstname.dirty " danger > FirstName is required (b/w 4-12 chars)</p>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label primary floating>LAST NAME</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" formControlName="lastname" minlength="4" maxlength="10" required ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
  <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.lastname.errors && myForm.controls.lastname.dirty " danger> LastName is required (b/w 1-10 chars)</p>
</form>
```

Tell me how display error message in danger!

Comment: is this ionic app?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#sts=Reactive%20Forms

Answer (score 1):

```
     <form role="form" name="myForm" novalidate="">
       <div data-ng-show="myForm.controls.firstname.errors && myForm.controls.firstname.dirty" class="alert alert-danger alert-   dismissible" role="alert">
                <strong>FirstName is required (b/w 4-12 chars)</strong> 
            </div>

            <div data-ng-show="myForm.controls.lastname.errors && myForm.controls.lastname.dirty" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <strong>LastName is required (b/w 1-10 chars)</strong> 
            </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: some one saying Use "myForm.get.('firstname')"  i do no what it is